LuaTex : zhuyin ruby characters are not rendering correctly
I need to write Chinese and Japanese text, with Zhuyin being used for ruby text in Chinese (traditional), and Hiragana for Japanese. The ruby text for Japanese (Hiragana) is working fine but the Zhuyin ruby text is not rendering (there are crossed out boxes) except for the tone marks. I suspect it might have to do with the font being used "Noto Serif Traditional Chinese", but I'm not entirely as Zhuyin is supported by this font. the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}  
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setmainfont{NotoSerifTC-Medium.ttf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

(\ruby{文}{ㄡㄣˊ}\ruby{言}{ㄧㄢˊ}/\ruby{漢}{かん}\ruby{文}{ぶん})

\end{document}

Any possible fixes for this problem? on a side note, I also tried using Pinyin(Latin) for the ruby text and it turned out fine as well, like the Japanese ruby text.

I get 4 missing character warnings the first is Missing character: There is no ㄡ (U+3121) in font file:HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf:-kern;jfm=ujis!  I do not know luatexja well enough to easily say how to specify a different font than HaranoAjiMincho-Regular

You need to define a font that has the required glyphs. See section 8.3 in the documentation of luatexja for the relevant information.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% according to the documentation, this should go
%% before loading luatexja
\makeatletter
\def\ltj@stdmcfont{file:FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\makeatother

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setmainfont{FandolSong}% I don't have NotoSerifTC-Medium.ttf

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

(\ruby{文}{ㄡㄣˊ}\ruby{言}{ㄧㄢˊ}/\ruby{漢}{かん}\ruby{文}{ぶん})

\end{document}



thanks, this worked
